# How to Configure Path Params in Wso2 API manager 1.8?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using Wso2 API Manager 1.8 . I Want to Know how can I configure the path params
     that comes dynamically . I will explain with following example

```
 My API starts with context api/example/  and i have an end point 

 http://users/api/example/{Id}.json

 How to map the id variable with coming id value . ?
```

I Want to load 'id' with given value and show results accordingly . How can i do that ?

Comment: I am using the version WSO2-AM 1.8.0. I added APIs and working fine. Now i have another scenario that i need to read multiple path parameter and also i need to append these values with production 
url. To do that i added URL Pattern as,{param1}/{param12}, but i am getting 404 error while accessing the API.Any help to add resources to API and dynamic path parameter reading ?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the synapse you can read the added parameters to property as follow

```
<property name="val1" expression="get-property('uri.var.param1')"/>
<property name="val2" expression="get-property('uri.var.param1')"/>
```

Then these values cane be appended to production url using REST_URL_POSTFIX property[1] as follow.

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('/',$ctx:val1,'/',$ctx:val2)"  scope="axis2"/>
```

this will append the values to production url -> e.g http://ip/mytest/param1/param2.

wso2 apimanger support custom mediation extenstion[2] .so In your case you can add an insquence and make your logic within that.

1.https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/HTTP+Transport+Properties
2.https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Adding+Mediation+Extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can use url-templates for that.

When you create the API add a resource as follows

under **url-pattern /{context}/{version}/** `{id}.json`

This will direct any request with the `http://users/api/example/{Id}.json` pattern to the above resource.

**NOTE:** If you haven't set the API version as default and say you have set the version as 1.0.0 at API creation then you might need to adjust the request as follows. (just after context part you need to add the API version)
`http://users/api/example/1.0.0/{Id}.json`